# Mono to Stereo conversion

Tags: c, algorithm, audio

I have the following issue here: I get a block of bytes (uint16_t*) representing audio data, and the device generating them is capturing mono sound, so obviously I have mono audio data, on 1 channel. I need to pass this data to another device, which is expecting interleaved stereo data (so, 2 channels). What I want to do is basically duplicate the 1 channel in data so that both channels of the stereo data will contain the same bytes. Can you point me to an efficient algorithm doing this?

Thanks,
f.

Comment: What audio format/framework are you using?

Comment: Anders also asked for the framework.

Comment: Framework is nothing special, 1 device sending in data to a pointer (void*) and tells me the number of samples (via a callback), and the other device takes this number of samples and the same void* and plays audio (device number two is called from this callback). Device number 2 expects this data to be interleaved stereo.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding, problem solved :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want interleaved stereo samples then you could use a function like this:

```
void interleave(const uint16_t * in_L,     // mono input buffer (left channel)
                const uint16_t * in_R,     // mono input buffer (right channel)
                uint16_t * out,            // stereo output buffer
                const size_t num_samples)  // number of samples
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i)
    {
        out[i * 2] = in_L[i];
        out[i * 2 + 1] = in_R[i];
    }
}
```

To generate stereo from a single mono buffer then you would just pass the same pointer for in_L and in_R, e.g.

```
interleave(mono_buffer, mono_buffer, stereo_buffer, num_samples);
```

Comment: Next time you remove an edit, could you at least inform the person who contributed? :-/

Comment: Sure, although I'm not sure how I'd do that?

Comment: I forgot to add a comment after I added the in-place version. My bad.

Comment: No problem. FYI I felt that your edit, although it contained useful information, did not belong as part of this answer, and should perhaps have been added as a separate answer. I see you've now done this: +1!

Comment: This is close, but it only works for a special case, when the frame depth is only one byte.  I extended this answer to work for any frame depth.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to do the conversion in-place to save some memory. Depends on how small an amount of memory the device in question has. So you might want to use something like this instead of Paul R's approach:

```
void interleave(uint16_t buf[], const int len)
{
    for (int i = len / 2 - 1, j = len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        buf[j--] = buf[i];
        buf[j--] = buf[i];
    }
}
```

When getting the sound data from the mono device, you allocate a buffer that's twice as big as needed and pass that to the mono device. This will fill half the buffer with mono audio. You then pass that buffer to the above function, which converts it to stereo. And finally you pass the buffer to the stereo device. You save an extra allocation and thus use 33% less memory for the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Pass to both channels the same pointer? If that violates `restrict` rules, use `memcpy()`?

Sorry, but your question is otherwise to broad. API? OS? CPUArchitectures?

Comment: That's not working, I am not sending in data for each of the channels, I send in a whole bunch of bytes and device nr. 2 is separating them according to its needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to copy the buffer and duplicate it. As you haven't told us the format, how it is terminated, I can't give code, but it will look like a simple for loop.

```
int_16* allocateInterleaved(int_16* data, int length)
  int i;
  int *copy = malloc(sizeof(int_16)*length*2);
  if(copy == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
  }
  for(i =0; i<length; i++) {
    copy[2*i] = data[i];
    copy[2*i+1] = data[i]; 
  }
  return copy;
}
```

forgive any glaring typos, my C is a bit rusty. typdef in whatever type you need for signed 16bit into int_16. Don't forget to free the copy buffer, or better yet reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interleave the data, but if the frame length is anything greater than one, none of the above solutions will work.  The below code can account for variable frame lengths.

```
void Interleave(BYTE* left, BYTE* right, BYTE* stereo,int numSamples_in, int frameSize)
{
    int writeIndex = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < numSamples_in; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < frameSize; k++)
        {
            int index = j * frameSize + k;

            stereo[k + writeIndex] = left[index];
            stereo[k + writeIndex + frameSize] = right[index];
        }
        writeIndex += 2 * frameSize;
    }
}
```