# how to do mono to stereo conversion?

Tags: audio, pcm, resampling

I am using libswresample to resample from any PCM format to 44.1kHz, 16bit int, stereo.

I was playing around with some audio volume analyzing of the resulting audio stream and I figured out that in case I have 44.1kHz, 16bit int mono as the source, I have roughly the formular:

```
leftSample = sourceSample / sqrt(2);
rightSample = sourceSample / sqrt(2);
```

But I was expecting:

```
leftSample = sourceSample;
rightSample = sourceSample;
```

(In case the source is stereo, I simply have `leftSample = leftSourceSample; rightSample = rightSourceSample;`.)

My expectation comes from several sources:

1. That is how my own straight forward solution would probably have been.
2. I searched a bit around and other people seem to do the same, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292905/mono-to-stereo-conversion).
3. In a very common ReplayGain implementation (the only one I know actually, used basically everywhere, I think initially from mp3gain; one copy can be seen [here](https://github.com/avuserow/ffmpeg-replaygain/blob/master/gain_analysis.c)), it also does it:

   ```
   switch ( num_channels) {
   case  1: right_samples = left_samples;
   case  2: break;
   default: return GAIN_ANALYSIS_ERROR;
   }
   ```

   This is esp. relevant because ReplayGain was calibrated by this implementation using a reference sound (a pink noise, can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/avuserow/ffmpeg-replaygain/raw/master/ref_pink.wav)) which is in mono.

   In the ReplayGain specification, it is also calculated like this (see [here](http://replaygain.hydrogenaudio.org/proposal/rms_energy.html)).

My confusion raised after I tried to implement ReplayGain myself and I stumbled upon this.

So, some questions:

1. Why does libswresample do this?
2. Is this expected in libswresample or a bug? (I'm trying to understand from the source (e.g. [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libswresample/swresample.c)) but I haven't fully understood it all yet.) I added a bug report [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1792).
3. What is the "right" solution?
4. What are other players doing?
5. What is a common soundcard doing if you feed mono samples to it?

(I also posted this question on [avp.stackexchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4910/how-to-do-mono-to-stereo-conversion) now; maybe that is a better place to ask about this, not sure.)

Comment: It probably has to do with mono channel being the equivalent perceived loudness from two combined stereo channels. Thus, 60dB from the left and right channels is louder than 60dB combined loudness since the sounds from left and right must be added in some fashion in a stereo system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation is one correct implementation of "panning" a mono signal into a stereo field. If you pan, instead all the way left or all the way right you want the signal strength to be the same as if it had been panned in the middle, so panned left would be:

```
//left panning
leftSample = sourceSample;
rightSample = 0;
//right panning
leftSample = 0;
rightSample = sourceSample;
//center panning (same power as hard left/right conversion/)
leftSample = sourceSample * sqrt(2)/2;
rightSample = sourceSample * sqrt(2)/2;
```

However, if you are converting from mono to stereo, your intuition is correct. There no reason to lower the level since you wont be comparing centered to panned signals. The best way to go is to leave the signal at full strength:

```
//mono to stereo conversion
leftSample = sourceSample;
rightSample = sourceSample;
```

It's also possible that they are leaving some post-s/r conversion gain change, but the level seem arbitrary.

Comment: Ok, this adds some clarity. But I still don't see why libswresample is doing that. Are other libs doing the same?

Comment: I'm not familiar with libswresample, so I can't say for sure. It's possible the library has some reason for  doing like panning options, or leaving headroom for SR conversion (but that's a lot of headroom and seems like a coincidence that that's the amount of headroom they give). It sounds like a bug to me, though.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [source](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libswresample/swresample.c). It has many options which I don't really understand, e.g. Center Mix Level, LFE, Rematrix, Dither scale, Rectangular dither, Triangular dither with high pass, Matrixed Stereo Encoding, Blackman Nuttall Windowed Sinc, Kaiser Windowed Sinc.

Comment: Holy hell! So much for abstraction. Well without proper documentation for that stuff, I would guess you should set center mix level to 1 (or maybe .9 or something if you get distortion). That probably sets the level of the center channel when mixed to stereo or surround. Note that the default is 1/sqrt(2), so that reenforces my guess.